# Train arrival Paradox

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, word-problem

I am unable to understand the solution to this question: "At your subway station, you notice that of the two trains running in opposite directions which are supposed to arrive with the same frequency, the train going in one direction comes first 80% of the time, while the other train going in the opposite direction comes first 20% of the time. What do you think could be happening?

The solution provided is: " Assume that your arrival in the station is uniformly distributed. If both trains run every ten minutes and train A comes into the station at 1, 1:10, 1:20,..while train B comes at 1:12, 1:22, ..then train A will come first 80% of the time." I don't understand the logic here.

Comment: Maybe you are confused about this: When they say train A arrives first "80% of the time", they really mean that if you selected a time of day at random, then waited for at train to arrive, 80% of the time the train arriving first would be train A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ones digit of the minutes of your arrival is 0 or 1, then you see the B train first.  If the ones digit of the minutes of your arrival is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, then you see the A train first.

Your arrival time is uniformly distributed...

Comment: This explanation helped me understand what the answer meant the best. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the eastbound train arrives at 2:00 and then the westbound train at 2:01.

Then the eastbound train arrives at 3:00 and then the westbound train at 3:01.

Then the eastbound train arrives at 4:00 and then the westbound train at 4:01.

Then the eastbound train arrives at 5:00 and then the westbound train at 5:01.

And so on.

Is there anything in this that implies they don't arrive with equal freqencies --- once per hour?

Now add a bit of randomness so that occasionally --- say $20\%$ of the time, the westbound train arrives first.

Answer (score 0):

In every slice of 10 minutes, for 2 minutes (say 1:00 to 1:02) the train to arrive is A, and for the next 8 minutes (say 1:02 to 1:10), the train to arrive is B.

The probabilities are 2/10 for A and 8/10 for B.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the time interval from 1:10 to 1:20.  If you arrive between after 1:10 and before 1:12, train B will be first to arrive. If you arrive after 1:12 and before 1:20, train A will be next to arrive.  The first interval is 2 minutes long and the second is 8 minutes long, so you are 4 times more likely to arrive in the second interval.